# Typical validity period of a J-1 visa

Tags: usa

In many places with information on J-1 I read that the validity period of the J-1 visa may not coincide with the validity of the DS-2019 form that indicates the start and end date of the program; and that status (being allowed to be in the US) differs from visa (being allowed to enter the US).

I could not find any information, though, on how long a J-1 visa is going to be (typically) valid.

Does anyone have some experience here? For example, with a DS-2019 that specifies a program duration of one years, how long will the issued visa be valid? What if the program specifies two years?

Comment: As far as I know, this is at the discretion of the visa officer. If they consider you to be "low-risk", they will issue a visa for the complete duration of your program. Citizens of some countries often only get shorter visas - at least for F visa, it is like this. In any case, the visa will not last longer than the DS-2019.

Comment: _In any case, the visa will not last longer than the DS-2019._ That’s the bit I was concerned about, thanks. I’ll nudge my sponsor to put two years on that form. Feel free to turn that comment into an answer!

Comment: Generally, the length of validity for each nationality and type of US visa can be found on the [Visa Reciprocity Tables](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country.html). Enter the country of nationality, and then select the visa classification from the drop-down menu.

Comment: Thanks for that link! It says 60 months; but I guess it is still bounded by the DS-2019, as DCTLib said.

Comment: @user102008 might you add your comment, as the answer (with the link and a portion of the content on the linked page), as it was accepted by OP as what was needed? Put it in and I'll upvote :D !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of validity of the J-1 visa should be the length given for J-1 visas for your country of nationality in the Department of State's [reciprocity tables](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country.html), or until the end of your J-1 program, whichever is shorter. See [9 FAM 402.5-6(E)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040205.html#M402_5_6_E)(c):

> You should also note the program end date as it appears in the
>   electronic record and ensure that the J visa is issued with a validity
>   that corresponds to the program end or to the reciprocity schedule for
>   the country of the applicant's nationality, whichever is shorter.

And [9 FAM 402.5-6(I)(7)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040205.html#M402_5_6_I_7)(b):

> J-1 visas must be issued for the program dates listed on the Form
>   DS-2019, unless where excepted in [...], or unless visa reciprocity
>   only allows for a shorter validity period.

You said in the comments that the J-1 length in the reciprocity table for your country is 5 years, so if your program will end in less than 5 years, your J-1 visa should be valid until the end of your J-1 program; and if your program will end in more than 5 years, the visa should be valid for 5 years.